# Cast angular scope variable to strong type

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I want to cast an angular scope variable to a type:

It might look something like this:

```
app.controller( 'PageLayoutController', function ( $scope )
{
    // Scope properties
    (PageMap)$scope.PageMap;
```

or

```
app.controller( 'PageLayoutController', function ( $scope )
{
    // Scope properties
    $scope.PageMap: PageMap;
```

Is it possible or must i declare a separate variable?:

```
var pageMap: PageMap;
$scope.PageMap = pageMap;
```

This is for typeahead sake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way, create a type deriving from [`IScope`](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angularjs/angular.d.ts#L639) and add your properties to it. Example:

```
 interface PageLayoutVM extends ng.IScope{
     PageMap : PageMap;
 }
```

and use it

```
app.controller( 'PageLayoutController', function ( $scope:PageLayoutVM)
```

You will get `ng.IScope` only if you have angular.d.ts typings used in your application.

Also to add on, with the usage of TypeScript it is much easier to use it with `controllerAs` syntax and defining properties on the controller itself rather than using scope to set view model properties.

Something like:

```
 export interface PageLayoutVM {
     PageMap : PageMap;
     someChangehandler:(val:string)=>void;
 }

 class PageLayoutController implements PageLayoutVM {

    PageMap : PageMap; //public is implicit

    static $inject = ['$scope', 'myService']; //Just for demo if you are using scope specific methods like watch
    constructor(private $scope:ng.IScope,
                private myService:IMyService){

    }

    someChangehandler(val:string){ //Another public method
        this.myService.doSomething(val);
    }

    private doSomePrivateStuff(){
        //Do stuff...
    }

 }
```

With this when you write unit tests for your controller, you can write the test in TS itself with the type definitions it will be easy to lookup controller properties while writing tests.

Comment: This is beautiful <wipes tear from eye> thank you. Makes sense... Thanks for providing the extension of IScope dude. (you need it for `$scope.$watch`)

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 You are welcome. Infact the other answer also has been updated (edited inside grace period) to specify scope extends, but i mentioned it before that...

Comment: @PSL: Was just checking what the interface is! - TBH I don't normally bother with it unless I specifically want something from `IScope` in the controller.

Comment: @JonEgerton More often you need it if you are setting your view model properties on the scope and you more commonly end up using built in eventing, watchers, common methods added on the rootScope constructors etc.  That is where controller itself as viewmodel is more beautiful with typescript and is generally recommended pattern as well with the support for controllerAs syntax availability. But generic sense i agree with you, wonder why would you update your answer with extension though if that is the case.. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you should define an interface and declare $scope with it:

```
interface IPageLayoutScope extends ng.IScope {
    PageMap: PageMap;
}

app.controller( 'PageLayoutController', function ( $scope: IPageLayoutScope)
```

That way `$scope.PageMap` will be defined already.

Comment: Thanks man, i like PSL answer with the extends of ng.IScope which solves the $scope dependancies!